# Collective knowledge from Workplace?

Tags: discussion, meta

Would anyone be interested in helping create a structure for gathering and organizing the collective knowledge of this community into a reference source that's more like a bunch of how-tos or tips/tricks, rather than just questions and answers.

For many of the common questions, a wiki that answers them would be useful. I'm thinking of extending that to include things like stuff you should know when starting a new job, writing a resume, doing a performance review, etc.

Suggestions/ideas or pointers to similar efforts would be appreciated.

Comment: http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2947/168

Comment: I think [this post](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4932/practical-meme-handbook-for-navigating-the-workplace) would qualify as collective knowledge and ideas from TWP.